Why is the execution time of my multi-threading program not constant?
I wrote a C program aimed at loading data with multithreading from a file. There is no pseudo-random code in my program and it always reads the same file and load the same amount of data.
When I run the program several times, I get this behaviour :
% time ./test_parallel   
./test_parallel  5,04s user 1,03s system 82% cpu 7,345 total
% time ./test_parallel 
./test_parallel  4,93s user 1,00s system 211% cpu 2,804 total
% time ./test_parallel 
./test_parallel  4,99s user 0,92s system 245% cpu 2,411 total
% time ./test_parallel 
./test_parallel  4,94s user 0,87s system 301% cpu 1,928 total
% time ./test_parallel 
./test_parallel  4,93s user 0,73s system 370% cpu 1,526 total

Why isn't my program using the approximate same amount of CPU at each execution ? How to get a more predictable and good behaviour ?
I am under Mac M1.

There can be difference in memory and file caching from run to run.

The user time is rather stable which make sense. The system time tends to reduce, certainly due to caching (and page management). The first run can be slower also due to power management (C-States & P-States). Once a file is cached in RAM, I do not expect multiple thread to load it faster unless the loading is clearly compute-bound. In fact, for sequential accesses, using multiple threads is generally not very useful on mainstream SSD. It is even detrimental for HDDs and low-end SSDs.

@JérômeRichard Thank you for your answer. I map the file, then store the data in arrays using memcpy, unmap the file, and then process the data with threads. I can't understand why the CPU usage differs so much, and this way, between executions.

I think we cannot help more than that. We need either to reproduce this on our machine or you need to use profilers to know what is happening. Hardware counters is certainly the way to go but I have no idea how to track them on Apple systems nor even if they are such counters on M1 CPUs.
